# How to write a semi ObservableCollection<T> class with store removing data capability to use in wcf services?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, observablecollection

I create a class inherited from ObservableCollection to any item remove from collection store in a list in class:

```
[Serializable]
public class PreservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public PreservableCollection(){}

    public PreservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection){}

    public PreservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list){}

    protected List<T> _removedItems = new List<T>();

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        _removedItems.Add(this[index]);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> AllItems
    {
        get { return this.Concat(_removedItems).AsEnumerable(); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> RemovedItems
    {
        get { return _removedItems.AsEnumerable(); }
    }
}
```

This worked properly but when i use this class as a type in wcf to transfer between server and client, the serializing and deserialising object of this type cause loosing the _removedItems field data.

I test any way with googling (datamember attribute, implement ISerializable interface, ignoring inheritance of ObservableCollection and implement ObservableCollection with decompile code)
but never worked!

**Question:**
How to i have a semi ObservableCollection class with store removing data capability to use in wcf services?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to do this, is to use a Data Transfer Object, and translate the collection before I sent it.

You can read more about it here: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

**The problem in your code, is the protected field, the serializer does not inherit from your class, thus it has no access.**

So 2 ways,either use DTO, or make your field public.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try adding the following for WCF

`[DataContract]
public class MyGenericType2<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    T theData;
}`


Take also a look here, about serialization rules:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx   and here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx